# How can we write scrolling code in Appium with Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium

How can we write scrolling code in Appium with Java?

Here is what I want to do,

1. Open the application.
2. Scroll down to the footer.
3. Scroll back up.

This is the code that I have written:

base.java ;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base {
    
public static  AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException
{
    
     File f = new File("src");
     File fs = new File(f, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"oppo A5s");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Uiautomator2");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1.0");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);        
     return driver ;
    

}
```

Scolling class;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class ScrolingDemo extends base {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>driver=capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollToEnd(100000)"));
   driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollToBeginning(100000)"));
```

you can use adroidUIAutomater class's uiscrollable,

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable

Comment: thank you its works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try putting this method in the base class:

```
    public void scrollToWebElement(WebElement locator)
    {
        try
        {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", locator);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to scroll to webelement.  WebElement is not visible.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, sir, which locator I have given here I did not understand.

Comment: basically, I want to just scroll the page at the bottom and then comes up with that which locator I use .

Comment: WebElement myLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']"));  
    scrollToWebElement(myLocator);

Comment: This should take you directly to your webelement.  Not sure why you want to scroll all the way to the bottom.

Comment: He want to scroll application not webapp

Comment: hi @PDHide do you help me I know this way how we scroll to the bottom in mobile application but  the other scenery I did not understand how we go down to up

Comment: Could you add your code for scrolling down ,

Comment: scrollIntoView will work for both native app and mobile browser.  To scroll up, try using Action class or TouchAction.

Comment: @PDhide this is my scrolling code on the mobile device its work fine       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

   JavascriptExecutor JavascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

   driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"WebView\"));");

   Thread.sleep(500);

   System.out.println("Scrolled time: " + i);

   }

Comment: now am using this code for up side-scrolling but it did not work    
   System.out.println("****************Scrolled up starts****************");

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

   JavascriptExecutor jb = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

   driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Animation\"));");

   Thread.sleep(500);

   System.out.println("Scrolled time: -" + i);

Comment: @ToastMan have you any examples and any queries to ..??

Comment: Example code for side scrolling here = <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181636/how-to-scroll-right-in-a-menu-bar-in-appium>